# Are there any tools that estimate XML schema based on documents only?

Tags: xml, xsd

Or to display some statistics at least. I need some statistics like this:
* All documents have root node  with two children  and 
* 50% of the documents have product/picture node
* Documents have between 1 and 10 product/a/comment nodes

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [XSD.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(VS.71).aspx) if you are using Visual Studio.